# Themes and AlertDialog with list adapter

Tags: android, list, themes, android-alertdialog

I have troubles with AlertDialog and my custom themes. I have 2 themes Black and Light defined like this

```
<style name="AppThemeBlack" parent="android:Theme.Black">
...................
</style>

<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="android:Theme.Light">
...................
</style>
```

I have base activity that apply theme according to preferences

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Util.SetTheme(this, Config.getInstance().getUITheme());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

.............................

private static int GetThemeIdByName(String themeName)
{
   if (themeName.equals("AppThemeLight"))
       return R.style.AppThemeLight;
   else if (themeName.equals("AppThemeBlack"))
       return R.style.AppThemeBlack;
   return R.style.AppThemeLight;
}

public static void SetTheme(Context context, String themeName)
{
    int id = GetThemeIdByName(themeName);
    context.setTheme(id);
}
```

All activities inherited from this BaseActivity. So my themes applied for every activity in the application.
But there is problem with AlertDialog
By default in AndroidManifest defined Light theme

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppThemeLight" >
```

I create AlertDialog like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ObjectListAdapter<TPartnerSimple> adapter = new ObjectListAdapter<TPartnerSimple>(this, list);
dlg.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){....});
dlg.show();
```

This adapter use item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName_ObjectListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Position 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When application use light theme list displayed with white background and black text.
But if I apply black theme it list displayed with white background and WHITE text (as defined in BlackTheme)
So I can't see items text

Why dialog uses white text defined in black theme and not uses black background defined there?
How could I change background of dialog to black to see items text using themes?

Comment: Had you try to set also getApplicationContext().setTheme(id);